# ¿Cómo mostrar imagenes de forma dinamica en una escena con JavaFX?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, javafx

Contexto: Estoy creando una sistema de gestion de equipos de computo para un proyecto de la universidad, necesito crear una vista como la que se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

Donde aparezca una imagen con la marca y modelo de acuerdo al numero de registros en una base de datos **SQL**.
El punto es que no tengo idea de como implementarlo en **JavaFX**. Lo puedo hacer con un gridPane?, alguien ya ha hecho algo similar?.

Buenos noches, y muchas gracias por el tiempo que se toman para contestar.

[image: Prototipo "Equipos a diagnosticar" "Sistema de Gestion de Equipos de Computo"]

Comment: podrías agregar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: si todos los nodos son del mismo tamaño una opción sería usar tilepane

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un Anchorpane -> HPane -> y dentro ImageView o Boton con CSS para agregar la imagen.